# how to pass value into html form in Bottle?

Tags: python, html, bottle

I’m novice to python and Bottle but I’m trying to develop a simple web application which will inventory items in boxes that company receives.
Using Bottle I was able to create a form which has 2 text boxes and one ‘Save’ button. I scan box ID and it get into text box1. Then I scan item ID and it get into text box2. Then I click on Save button.
It works … but after I click on ‘Save’ the form get reloaded i.e. it open blank page and  I have to move back page, delete the content from text box1 and do it again until I switch to the next Box which will start with empty box1 and box2
My request: I want that every time I click on ‘Save’ button it submitted data into my database but the form stay intact i.e. not reloaded and the content of text box1 get empty. Then I could just scan next item and so on until I complete all items.
Could please someone help me with that?
Here’s how my code look for now in Bottle template:

```
<form action="/accession" method="GET">
      Scan Box: <input type="text" size="18" name="package"> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      Scan Item:  <input type="text" size="13" name="sample">
<input type="submit" name="save"  value="Save" >
```

**
I slightly changed the form and now it behaves differently i.e. when I click on "Save" it stays on the same page ( which is OK ) but it empties the content of both text boxes. 
I need that only one text box be cleared but another one keep the content. How could I do it?
Thanks 
**
I noticed that I could use 'value' attribute with "text" box .. like this:

```
Scan Box: <input type="text" value="123" name="package">
```

In my case the value "123" should be dynamic. I do have the value in my python script that I want to replace with "123" but I don't know how to pass it into the form.
Could someone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a template.  Here are [the docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#templates) for Bottle's built-in templating; I happen to prefer [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) but you can decide which to use once you've mastered the concept.

Basically, you'll create a template file that is the html you want to return.  It will include something like this:

```
Scan Box: <input type="text" value="{package}" name="package">
```

And your Bottle function (which you haven't posted, so I'm making a guess here) will look something like this:

```
@route('/myform')
def submit():
    the_package = zzz  # get the value however your application chooses
    return template('form1', package=the_package)  # your template file is form1.tpl
```

The value of `the_package` will automatically be substituted where `{package}` appears in your template file.

Please try the template examples in the Bottle documentation and let us know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Following your advice I'm all set now.

Comment: Happy to hear it!  (If my answer solved your problem then please "accept" it as such.  Thanks!)

Comment: How about reading it in javascript that nested in .tpl? the {{package}} won't work.

Comment: Thanks so much from me too - I was expecting some tricky Javascript/AJAX shenanigans but it never occurred to me to simply feed a variable to the input tag itself.  Genius.  This opens up a lot of doors - really appreciated!